# Test script in selenium to verify a webpage title

Tags: java, html, selenium, testing

I have written some code but it works only until it gets the webpage title.
When the title is verifying the code is giving test failed.

The scenario is as follows:

1. Go to the website: https://www.google.co.in
2. Search for your name: i.e. First name + last name
3. From the search result open the third link and verify the page title

Code is :

```
package sample;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class search_demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com/"); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Click on the search text box and send value  
        WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        element.sendKeys("Nishtha tiwari"); 
        element.submit();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        WebElement elem=  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#rso > div:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.r > a")));
        elem.click(); 

        driver.navigate().to("https://in.linkedin.com/in/nishtha-tiwari-40a95281");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String title =driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("Page title is:" + title);

        String expectedTitle = "LinkedIn: Log In or Sign Up ";


        if (title.equals(expectedTitle))
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        else  System.out.println("Test Failed");

        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the output/exception you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the "test failed". Update your question to be more specific. It's hard to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I looked at your code and checked page source of `Linked In page` I have found the title with ends `&nbsp;` That is reason it is always getting failed.

[image]

**Solutions**:

So to get rid of that you have two options.

**Option 1:** Remove all `&nbsp;` from string.

```
String title =driver.getTitle();
title = title.replaceAll("&"+"nbsp;", " "); 
title = title.replaceAll(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ");
System.out.println("Page title is:" + title);

String expectedTitle = "LinkedIn: Log In or Sign Up";

    if (title.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(expectedTitle))
        {
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        }
    else  
        {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }
```

**Option 2:** Use contains instead.

```
String title =driver.getTitle();
System.out.println("Page title is:" + title);

String expectedTitle = "LinkedIn: Log In or Sign Up";

    if (title.contains(expectedTitle))
        {
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        }
    else  
        {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }
```

Comment: thanks a lot ...after using option 1 ,i got output as test passed...!!!

Comment: Glad to help you.Please Upvote the answer once you get the reputation over 15.